# Facebook account kit resend code using phone call

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, account-kit

I am an Android developer and I have a question. How can I enable Account Kit to allow users to receive the login code via a phone call instead of the SMS or Facebook notification code?I cannot seem to find this in the Account kit official documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voice calls and Facebook notifications are only available as secondary methods of receiving your code if the SMS doesn't arrive. You can turn these on/off by setting setVoiceCallbackNotificationsEnabled and setFacebookNotificationsEnabled in your AccountKitConfigurationBuilder.

Voice calls cannot be used as the primary source of code verification

Comment: setVoiceCallbackNotificationsEnabled() does not appear in my AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder object unlike setFacebookNotificationsEnabled(boolean obj) which does. How do I get to access it?I am using the 4.20.0 account-kit-sdk version.

Comment: Yeah voice notification was added in 4.24 I think. Try upgrading to the latest (4.27.1) to get that